# Getting Session Value in Master Page - PageLoad

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I have a master page on which I have a dropdown of Language. I save dropdown's selected value in session. and want to check on page load that what's the value in session. But it gives exception because on page load, there is nothing in session.
Can anyone tell me what method should I call before page load in which I can set session to a default value?

Thanks in advance.

```
protected void ddlLanguage_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["Language"] = ddlLanguage.SelectedValue;
    }

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {

            ddlLanguage.SelectedValue = Session["Language"].ToString();
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could initialize your session variable to a default value inside the Page_Init event. So by the time the Page_Load event is fired, at least you would have a value to check against.

Alternatively, you could just check the Session variable for a null value in the Page_Load event & not try and use its value if indeed it is null.

For this second option, change your code to be something like:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (!IsPostBack)
    {

        ddlLanguage.SelectedValue = Session["Language"] == null ? "0" : Session["Language"].ToString();
    }
```

Replace the zero in the true condition of the ternary operator with whatever default value you have in your dropdown list.

Answer (score 2):

You have to check it before using it because when you are trying to get the value from the session it is null and not assigned any value yet.

```
 if (Session["Language"] != null)
 {
      ddlLanguage.SelectedValue = Session["Language"].ToString();
 }
```

Comment: it's really confusing decision.. In this situation I mark answer to the one who has less points :-s

Comment: that's not issue. I am just kidding. Good luck anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

No need to set default option in page init event, you can set language dropdown in page load event also like this ways :

## Master page Code

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            if (Session["culture"] != null)
                ddlLanguage.SelectedValue = Session["culture"].ToString();
            else
            {
                ddlLanguage.SelectedValue = "en-US";
                Session["culture"] = "en-US";
            }
        }
    }

    protected void ddlLanguage_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["culture"] = ddlLanguage.SelectedValue;
    }
```

=================

By this way I can preserve selected language in session and can use in whole application.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Page_PreLoad` event to set your session variable's value...

Comment: really? between y dont you check if Session["Language"] is null or not, like suggested by Muhammad Akhter?